# Post message on facebook wall from android.

Tags: android, facebook

I have sucessfully login to facebook from myapp and got the accesstoken but when i post the message on my wall i got the folowing exception.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10}}
```

Code is:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "hello ...");
parameters.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());  
try {
    String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
    } catch (IOException e) 
{}
```

Comment: Have you give facebook publish_stream permission to post from your application ?

Comment: i have given publish_stream option while autherzing mFacebook.authorize(MainActivity.this,PERMISSIONS, new DialogListener(){

Answer (score 0):

Please give publish_stream permission from your own application.

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
            new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream",};
```

When you initialize login button at that time you need to pass the permission.

```
 mLoginButton.init(this, mFacebook,PERMISSIONS);
```